# How do you programatically create decimal fields in Drupal forms?

Tags: forms

I simply need to be able to have a text field and validate if input is a decimal number like 100.00, 0.1, 10.6, etc.

I'm using Drupal 7.

Updated question to indicate 'programatic' solution (using Form API).

Comment: What kind of forms? Form API forms? Node edit forms? Webform forms?.. Also, have you read [Form API reference](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal?/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7)? Section about [#element_validate](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal?/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#element_validate)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can't think of a better solution than to use a standard textfield with the [`element_validate_number()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/element_validate_number/7) validator:

```
$form['element'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => t('Title'),
  '#element_validate' => array('element_validate_number'),
);
```

If you need something more complicated than the `is_numeric()` that gets run by `element_validate_number()` you just need to provide your own validation function, or if you want to mess with the widget itself then create your own element type using [`hook_element_info()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_element_info/7)

Comment: That's what I put in comment before OP clarified it is indeed about Form API. Too bad I wasn't fast enough to post my answer after clarification :P +1 from me anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Under Strucuture->content_type->manage fields :
There is **field type** called Decimal where you can get a textfield having only decimal numbers allowed with validation.

[image]

for programmatically adding decimal field you can ,

```
$field = array(
    'field_name' => abc_decimal,
    'type' => 'number_decimal',
);
```

Comment: After question update, your answer does not fit anymore. Well, question was totally unclear, so I guess you was a bit too fast to answer.